# Ploting the time and temperature using the heat equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the time (48 hours) on x and the temperature on y using the 1D heat equation:

[image]

I think the name of the method I used is the finite difference method. So far this is my code:

Does anyone know what are my mistakes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 0.5    
Ta = 20     
T0 = 40      
D = 1E-4    
tau = 48*3600  
dt = 10*60   
dx = 0.001   
Nt = int(tau/dt)+1  
Nx = int(L/dx)+1    
total_time=48*3600
t=np.arange(0, total_time, 10*60)
x = [j*dt for j in range(Nx)] 
T = np.zeros((Nt,Nx))
          
for j in range(Nx):
    T[0,j] = Ta     # T(x,t=0) = Ta

T[0,0] = T0         # T(x=0,t=0) = T0

for i in range(1,Nt): 
    T[i,0] = T0     # T(x=0,t) = T0
    T[i,-1] = Ta    # T(x=L,t) = Ta

for i in range(Nt-1):
    for j in range(1, Nx-1):
        T[i+1, j] = T[i, j] + D * dt / (dx*dx) * (T[i, j+1] + T[i, j-1] - 2*T[i, j])

    plt.plot(t, T[i,:], label='temperature fluctuation')
    plt.xlabel('t (s)')
    plt.ylabel('T (°C)')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[57], line 31
     28 for j in range(1, Nx-1):
     29     T[i+1, j] = T[i, j] + D * dt / (dx*dx) * (T[i, j+1] + T[i, j-1] - 2*T[i, j])
---> 31 plt.plot(t, T[i, :], label='temperature fluctuation')
     32 plt.xlabel('t (s)')
     33 plt.ylabel('T (°C)')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2812, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2810 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2811 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2812     return gca().plot(
   2813         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2814         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1688, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445 """
   1446 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1447 
   (...)
   1685 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1686 """
   1687 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1688 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1689 for line in lines:
   1690     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:311, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    309     this += args[0],
    310     args = args[1:]
--> 311 yield from self._plot_args(
    312     this, kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey=ambiguous_fmt_datakey)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:504, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey)
    501     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    503 if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 504     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    505                      f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    506 if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    507     raise ValueError(f"x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have "
    508                      f"shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (288,) and (501,)
```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes that is part of my problem I should have 288 values of temperature (ploted on y) but i don't know how to obtain that.

Comment: `t=np.arange(0, total_time, 10*60)` << You could instead use `linspace` here to get exactly the number of values you want in `t`.

Comment: Regarding the plot: there are three variables here (time, 1D space, and temperature). The question says *time (48 hours) on x and the temperature on y* (presumably with the space coordinate held constant), but the code looks to be plotting space on x and temperature on y (with time held constant at the end of the simulation time).

Comment: I get this error message : RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Comment: @slothrop yes originally the code used to plot space on x and temperature on y. I then tried to modify the code to plot time on x and temperature on y, without success

Comment: Regarding the errors you were getting with overflows etc, it could be that the errors involved in a finite difference approximation are adding up and getting out of control. You could maybe do something like print `np.max(T)` and `np.min(T)` after each time step to see if you are getting weird results.

Answer (score 2):

The system reaches steady state before 1h. To simulate 48h, it is necessary to decrease D.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sys import exit

L = 0.5    
Ta = 20     
T0 = 40      
D = 1E-4    
total_time = 3600
dx = 0.01
dt = 0.2

t = np.arange(0, total_time + dt, dt)
x = np.arange(0, L + dx, dx) 

Nt = len(t)
Nx = len(x)

#### Caution ####
stability_limit = 0.5
array_size_limit = 5E6

if Nt*Nx <= array_size_limit and D*dt/dx**2 <= stability_limit:
    T = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))
else:
    print('Stop! Check dt and dx...')
    exit()
#################

for j in range(Nx):
    T[0,j] = Ta     # T(x,t=0) = Ta

T[0,0] = T0         # T(x=0,t=0) = T0

for i in range(1,Nt): 
    T[i,0] = T0     # T(x=0,t) = T0
    T[i,-1] = Ta    # T(x=L,t) = Ta

for i in range(Nt-1):
    for j in range(1, Nx-1):
        T[i+1, j] = T[i, j] + D * dt / (dx*dx) * (T[i, j+1] + T[i, j-1] - 2*T[i, j])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('T (°C)')
plt.grid()

i_show = [0, 10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000]
colors = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 
          'yellow', 'gray', 'purple', 'lightblue', 'sienna']

for i, c in zip(i_show, colors):
    label = f'{t[i]:.1f} s'
    ax.plot(x, T[i, :], c=c, label=label)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]